# Bootstrap tooltip usage with the actual example tooltip buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

In the "Four directions" example, four buttons have tooltips on the left, top, bottom, and right.

I am trying to replicate this in my own html file, bootstrap, jquery, css, etc. are set up correctly.

However, the bootstrap docs say this is opt-in functionality meaning I must initialize it myself, the example code they give for usage is this:

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

so I wrapped that in script tags above my closing head tag in the html file, but it doesn't work. I know the #example part is probably incorrect syntax, but I don't know what # signifies and what to put here to make it hook to the example "Four directions" code, which is this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

Do I change the '#example' to '#button' to associate it with button type, to '#btn btn-default' to associate it with the class, or '#tooltip' to associate it with data-toggle, or '#right', '#left', '#top', '#bottom' in four copied lines to associate it with all of the data-placement tags, or '#title' to associate it with title?

I have found other stackoverflow answers with how to do this by pasting the code which seems to use alternative solutions such as associating it with "rel=" tag, but I'm trying to understand this not just copy paste working code.

Here is my HTML code for reference:

http://pastebin.com/83Cf8Csr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to include jquery and bootstrap.js before you start writing any js which uses the above. <s>Secondly you don't need this</s>

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

As you are already using data-attributes which are there as an alternative to js code. You can use either but not both.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

the data-toggle and data-placement will initialize your tooltip.

---

That was my bad, I missed the part where it said opt in only.

So the problem in your case is you are trying to initialize tooltip on #example where there is no element with that id. Specify proper id or class. Secondly the data-attributes will serve as options so you don't need options to initialize. Here is an example

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2631/)

Comment: @Gallaxhar Please check the edited answer. It is working now.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Suthar, can I ask you why I need to append # before an ID selector, but not for the button class?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2633/

Comment: button is a tag and not a class or id. Id's require #, classes require a '.' 
Here is a full tutorial on how to use jquery selectors correctly. You should read it. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/